# Django Noreverse Error for below code

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to set search navbar to work on my website but I keep getting this error which I do not to decode.

I'm using django 1.8 on Python 2.7

My template html file is below.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" role="search" action="{% url 'product' %}">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
</div>
</form>
```

My Overall url file is below.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'newsletter.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'newsletter.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about/$', 'ecommerse2.views.about', name='about'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^product/', include('product.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my local app urls is below.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import ProductDetailView, ProductListView
urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='Class_based_List_vie'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='Class_based_vie'),
    #url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)', 'product.views.product_det_vie_func', name='Detail_view_func'),
]
```

For the above code highlights the below line and getting 404 error with 
NoReverseMatch at /product/ and Reverse for 'product' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [].

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" role="search" action="{% url 'product' %}">
```

Please help me to rectify the above error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is causing due to the fact that you don't have any url with the name **"product"**.

If you are trying to search the products from the view "Class_based_List_vie", you should include the url tag in the template like this, `{% url 'Class_based_List_vie' %}`.

In the template, name of the url is included in the url tag, not the url itself.
If you are using multiple apps, then namespacing urls would be highly recommended.

If you could share the views ,it'd be more helpful to debug.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Its working Out now.

Comment: Then, could you please mark the answer as selected?

Answer (score 0):

The URL resolver is expecting a `pk` argument. Try:

```
action="{% url 'product' pk=product.id %}"
```

The `product` must be passed to the template renderer from the view

Comment: Thanks for your prompt Response. on editing the line i m getting the same error.NoReverseMatch at /product/

Reverse for 'product' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []